# LEFT OUTER JOIN with LIKE in SQLite not working

Tags: sql, sqlite, concatenation, wildcard

I think I'm going mad, but in SQL server management studio this query works perfectly well:

```
INSERT INTO [#Temp_main]
SELECT T1.ID, T2.ID
FROM [#Temp_other] T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table_with_lots_of_data] T2 ON ((T2.ID LIKE T1.ID+'%')
```

In other words, table `Temp_other` contains incomplete `ID`s (only the first few characters), and I want to match these to the `ID` in `Table_with_lots_of_data`, and `insert` the results into `Temp_main`.

The application I'm writing, which uses SQLite databases, was only returning the `T1.ID` (i.e. no complete `T2.ID`), so I popped it into the DB browser for SQLite for testing, and lo and behold this also returned only the `T1.ID`.

Any help as to what I'm missing with SQLite? I'm guessing it's something to do with the `T1.ID + '%'` wildcard bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is a concatenation operator is SQLite, not `+`:

```
(T2.ID LIKE T1.ID || '%')
```